# error: Failed: Template parse errors: 'mat-checkbox' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, angular-material

I create this code for testing my component.

I tried this code:

```
describe('Component: AddAlarms', () => {
    let component: AddAlarmsFormComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddAlarmsFormComponent>;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AddAlarmsFormComponent]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddAlarmsFormComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
});
```

when run `ng test` show this error:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2">
          [ERROR ->]<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (click)="sortbydate()">Dates</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
     "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/NotificationsComponent.html@12:10
```

I verify my module.ts and it's ok.  So, I have this:

```
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
```

Can you tell me, what is the problem?

Answer (score 33):

You need to add `imports` array above `declarations` like this :

Add it like this :

```
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
```

And add `imports` array like this :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
        MatCheckboxModule
   ],
   declarations: [AddAlarmsFormComponent]
})
```

Comment: The angular example code doesn't even have this, man their documentation is really sub par.

Answer (score 0):

Great!

But I think you need to import `MatCheckboxModule` in a `spec.ts` or you forgot to import the module in `"imports"` on `ngModule`!

Can you try and tell me if worked?

Comment: I decided on both, even on the `module` and in `spec.ts` But nothing happens